# A characteristic subgroup of the free group $F_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism, free-groups

Consider the free group $F_2 = ⟨x,y⟩$ and let $N$ be the smallest normal subgroup of $F_2$ containing $xyx^{−1}y^{−1}$.

$(a)$ Show that $x^2y^2x^{−2}y^{−2}$ is in $N$.

$(b)$ Show that any automorphism of $F_2$ sends $N$ to $N$.

For $(a)$ I think I have shown it and am wondering if it is valid. It goes as following:

Since N is a normal subgroup any two elements commute, and conjugation will be invariant. So, given $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ is an element of N, then:

$xxyx^{-1}y^{-1}x^{-1}$ is also in $N$ and $yxxyx^{-1}y^{-1}x^{-1}y^{-1}$ is also in $N$, and:

$yxxyx^{-1}y^{-1}x^{-1}y^{-1}=xyxyx^{-1}x^{-1}y^{-1}y^{-1}$
$=xxyyx^{-1}x^{-1}y^{-1}y^{-1}=x^2y^2x^{-2}y^{-2}$

Thus $x^2y^2x^{-2}y^{-2}$ is also in $N$

Is this a valid way to go about $(a)$?

As for $(b)$ I'm not really sure how to show this. Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: Normal subgroup does not mean abelian. It is not true that any two elements commute.

Answer (score 2):

Your reasoning is invalid since any two elements need not commute in $ N $, but a proof in a similar vein can be given.

**Hint:** $ xyx^{-1} y^{-1} = [x, y] $ is the commutator. What can you say about the quotient group $ F_2/N $?

Comment: It means $F_2/N$ is abelian.
How does this help to show that any automorphism maps N to N? I know that from the first isomorphism theorem, given any automorphism from $F_2$ to $F_2$, we then have $F_2/N$ is isomorphic to $F_2$, which would imply $F_2$ is abelian (this seems wrong). How could this show $N$ is mapped to $N$? Thanks!